# How to handle duplicates of duplicates?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

A [recent question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/78572/6986) about returning to the Dark Ages reminded me of another question I remembered seeing. After some digging, I found a [similar question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/9307/6986) and suggested it might be a duplicate of the OP's question.

Later, when I checked the close review queue, I noticed the Dark Ages question was being closed as a duplicate of a [different question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/9873/6986) that Mołot linked and was the question I had originally been thinking of but couldn't find.

Only thing is, the question Mołot linked is marked as a duplicate of the one I linked.

Is there a general policy on whether to mark questions as duplicates of duplicates? Should we link to any question in the chain or to the root?

Comment: I couldn't find any reference in the help center and on Meta after a quick search, but I think it would be best to mark a question as a duplicate of the original question, not as a duplicate of a duplicate. The goal is to show that the question has already been answered - not that the original of the referred question has answers. If you were to make longer chains, which could easily happen in the future a user would need to click through half a dozen questions just to find the answers he is searching for. That doesn't sound useful.

Comment: Are any of these similar enough to be merged into a canonical?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4800/how-to-handle-duplicates-of-duplicates?cb=1) (JK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general advice on Stack Overflow is to choose the "best one" to use as a canonical question, later duplicate questions can be merged or marked as duplicates of the canonical.

Generally the better canonical questions are a little more general so that they cover a larger portion of similar questions. As in:

How do I foo the bar?

Vs very specific questions, like:

How do I foo the bar in baz, while standing on one foot, on Friday afternoon, in Iceland?

Answer (score 2):

Duplicates can have variations on the theme. So if you're going to chose one, chose the one that is closest to OPs question, even if the one you're choosing is a duplicate of another question that is poorer fit.